# MYSQL: Convert rows to columns

Tags: mysql

Query :

```
SELECT  currency,alert_level,side, 
range_start,range_end      FROM   
AESFX_ALERT_CONFIG order by 
Side,Alert_Level
```

outputs

[image: output]

But I want output like this:

[image]

I have tried CASE but that doesnot solves my problem.

Comment: This type of query is called a pivot. It *can* be done in SQL, but I think issues of data display are best left to application code

Answer (score 0):

Use the `group by side, alert` predicate in your select

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: That doesn't works..